# Generate empty alt attribute in GWT

Tags: image, gwt, attributes, tags, alt

I working on a big project in GWT, and I would like to generate an empty alt attribute to image tags without rewrite the all image in the project. Is there any possibility in GWT?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to add empty alt tags, but this should add an empty alt attribute to every `img` tag on the page:

```
NodeList<Element> elems = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("img");
for (int i = 0; i < elems.getLength(); i++) {
  elems.getItem(i).setPropertyString("alt", "");
}
```

Alternatively, you could do `((ImageElement) elems.getItem(i)).setAlt("");`